# Explain AsyncEventingBasicConsumer behaviour without DispatchConsumersAsync = true

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I am trying out the RabbitMQ `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer` using the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Consumer";

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
    const string queueName = "myqueue";

    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);

        // consumer

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += Consumer_Received;
        channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

        // publisher

        var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        int i = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Message {++i}");
            channel.BasicPublish("", queueName, props, messageBody);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}

private static async Task Consumer_Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs @event)
{
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(@event.Body);

    Console.WriteLine($"Begin processing {message}");

    await Task.Delay(250);

    Console.WriteLine($"End processing {message}");
}
```

It works as expected. If I don't set the `DispatchConsumersAsync` property, however, the messages get consumed but the event handler never fires.

I find it hard to believe that this dangerous behaviour (losing messages because a developer forgot to set a property) is by design.

Questions:

1. What does `DispatchConsumersAsync` actually do?
2. What is happening under the hood in the case without `DispatchConsumersAsync`, where consumption is taking place but the event handler does not fire?
3. Is this behaviour by design?

Comment: It seems that `DispatchConsumersAsync` is a hack intended add async consummation without breaking existing functionality and require too much of a rewrite: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/380

Comment: Besides the other issue mentioned, there is a proposal to include a new API (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/970) and a PR to remove the old API (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/1212) in the next major version release.

Comment: "The messages get consumed but the event handler never fires" - this is not entirely accurate.  The messages do get delivered to your consumer, but they don't get ACK'd (unless you've set up auto ACK).  Therefore, after half an hour (the default RMQ setting), the messages will automatically go back onto the queue.

Answer (score 3):

The answer actually in your question. Yes, it is about design. [The documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consuming-async) explains and gives small example about async pattern.

> The client provides an async-oriented consumer dispatch implementation. This dispatcher can only be used with async consumers, that is, `IAsyncBasicConsumer` implementations.
> In order to use this dispatcher, set the `ConnectionFactory.DispatchConsumersAsync` property to `true`

So documentation has not enough information to answer your first question. However for second, if you want to use `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer`, you must to set `ConnectionFactory.DispatchConsumersAsync` property to `true`. It is design and rule of RabbitMq.
Also third question actually you answer yourself. Yes, for now it is about design of RabbitMq .net client.